# Flutter - Casting a type from one package to another

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, typeerror

I'm developing a app where I need to show the bluetooth(classic and BLE) devices and I'm able to discover using (flutter_bluetooth_serial) package and show in the ListView. I'm also able to connect the classic devices, but I'm unable to connect the BLE devices. What I understand is, I discovered the devices using (flutter_bluetooth_serial) and when I try to connect the BLE devices, it's failing because of the type issue. So what I did is, tried to cast the BluetoothDevice to the package (flutter_blue_plus.dart), but it is throwing below error. I want to connect to both classic and BLE devices. Can somebody give me some lights?

```
import 'package:flutter_bluetooth_serial/flutter_bluetooth_serial.dart';
import 'package:flutter_blue_plus/flutter_blue_plus.dart' as bluetoothLEManager;

   connectToExternalDevice(BluetoothDevice connectingDevice) async {
      if (connectingDevice.type == BluetoothDeviceType.le) {
      final bbleDevice = connectingDevice as bluetoothLEManager.BluetoothDevice; // here is where I'm getting the below exception
      print(bbleDevice);
  }
  try { // This part works if the connecting device is classic
    classicDevice = connectingDevice;
    await BluetoothConnection.toAddress(classicDevice.address).then((result) {
    isBluetoothConnected = true;
    connection = result;
    notifyListeners();
    connection?.input?.listen(onDataReceived).onDone(() {
    print("On done");
  });
  });
  } catch (exception) {
    print("exception");    
  }
}


Exception has occurred.
    •   
_TypeError (type 'BluetoothDevice' is not a subtype of type 'BluetoothDevice' in type cast where
  BluetoothDevice is from package:flutter_bluetooth_serial/flutter_bluetooth_serial.dart
  BluetoothDevice is from package:flutter_blue_plus/flutter_blue_plus.dart
```

Comment: You will need to map from one bluethoothDevice to another bluetoothDevice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two `BluetoothDevice` are completely different types, they just happen to have the same name. If you really want, you can use the constructor of `BluetoothDevice` from the second package and fill it with information obtained from the `BluetoothDevice` from the first package. For example:

```
final bbleDevice = bluetoothLEManager.BluetoothDevice.fromId(connectingDevice.address);
```

To know which property map to which, read the documentations. For example, you can see that the `address` property from the first package is described like this in the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_bluetooth_serial/latest/flutter_bluetooth_serial/BluetoothDevice/address.html):

> MAC address of the device or identificator for platform system (if MAC addresses are prohibited).

The `remoteId` parameter in the constructor from the second package is decribed like this in the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_blue_plus/latest/flutter_blue_plus/BluetoothDevice/BluetoothDevice.fromId.html):

> Create a device from an id
>
> - to connect, this device must have been discovered by your app in a previous scan
> - iOS uses 128-bit uuids the remoteId, e.g. e006b3a7-ef7b-4980-a668-1f8005f84383
> - Android uses 48-bit mac addresses as the remoteId, e.g. 06:E5:28:3B:FD:E0

From there you can tell that both properties represent the same thing.

---

Please note that there is no guarantee that this will always work for any cases, as diferent types may have different implementation and lack of properties existing on the other type.

Comment: Your solution seems to be working and was able to connect to BLE devices as well. I still need to do lot of testing, but this is good starting for me. Thanks Dhafin!